# Get a list of pictures and upload them with CasperJS?

Tags: upload, casperjs

I need some help with my CasperJS script.

I don't know how can I get all my pictures as an array from the current folder.
And how to loop to insert each one in the correct input.

Mmmh, difficult to explain so there is my starting code.
I put comment where I have problem.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://imgchili.net/', function() {

    // Get a list with all the picture from the current folder.

    // For each picture, click this button.
    this.mouseEvent('click', 'input.button1:nth-child(6)');

    this.fillSelectors('form#upload_form', {
        // Another loop here.
        '.grey > input:nth-child(2)':    /* First picture */,
        '.grey > input:nth-child(4)':    /* Second picture */,
        '.grey > input:nth-child(6)':    /* Third picture */
    }, true);

    casper.capture('captureTest.png');
});

// 8s can be too low if I have a lot of pictures!
casper.wait(8000, function() {
    casper.capture('captureResult.png');
})

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.fetchText('textarea.input_field:nth-child(11)'));
})

casper.run();
```

EDIT:

Thanks it helps me a lot. But I have problem to loop the inputs.

```
var fs      = require('fs'),
    casper  = require('casper').create(),
    myImages    = fs.list(fs.workingDirectory + '/img');

casper.start('http://imgchili.net/', function() {

    // For each image, click to add a new upload input.
    // Begin with 2 because 0 = "."" and 1 = "..".
    for (var i = 2; i < myImages.length; i++) {
        this.mouseEvent('click', 'input.button1:nth-child(6)');
    }

    // It doesn't work and show no error...
    for (var i = 2; i < myImages.length; i++) {

        j = i*2;

        input = '.grey > input:nth-child(' + j + ')';

        this.fillSelectors('form#upload_form', {
            input : '/img/' + myImages[i],
        }, false);

        // Even this part doesn't work
        console.log('i = ' + i + ' & imgName = ' + myImages[i]);
    }
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.capture('result.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: (Referring to your updated listing) If the `console.log()` inside the loop does not work, perhaps myImages is empty? How about putting `console.log(myImages)` just before the `casper.start()` command to make sure the `fs.list()` command worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) file system to get your current folder files.  Here is the [API Documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/).

The following gets your current folders files, and then filters all .png's into a new array. You can then use a loop to click the button for each image.  You will have to alter / add your own code because this does not accomplish the upload task.  This will should help you though.

```js
// vars
var fs            = require('fs');                // reference to phantomJS file      system
var myFolder      = fs.list(fs.workingDirectory); // gets all files in current folder
var myImages      = [];                           // only images from current folder
var url           = 'http://imgchili.net/';       // starting url
var fileType      = '.png';                       // image file type to filter by

casper.then(function() {
    // create array of just images 
    for (var i = 0; i < myFolder.length; i++) {
        if (myFolder[i].indexOf(fileType) != -1) {
            myImages.push(myFolder[i]);
        }     
    }
    // click for each image
    for (i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
        this.mouseEvent('click', 'input.button1:nth-child(6)');
    }
});

// wait for images to be uploaded
// set timeout or defaults to caspers step timeout
casper.waitForSelector('#page_body', function() {
    casper.capture('captureResult.png');
}, 15000);
```